# Running a sql script on a slow network

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a sql script which creates my applications tables, sequences, triggers etc. & inserts around 10k rows of data.

I am on a slow network and when I run this script from my local machine it takes a long time to finish. 
Wondering if there is any support in sqlplus (or sqldeveloper) to run this script on server. So the entire script is first transported to the server executed and then returns say a log file of the execution.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a shell script or similar on the server to run your SQL script.

Comment: Yes, but don't have that kind of access to the server or a co-located machine

Comment: How big is the file, how slow is 'slow', and how long is 'long'?

Comment: @BobJarvis the file is around 110MB with approximately 375,500 lines of script (~500 lines of DDL) and takes about an hour to execute.

Comment: Sorry - I meant "how slow is your network connection"? (It's so slow that...the bits have drag races with caterpillars! ...you'll be improving the baud rate when you upgrade to smoke signals! ...its speed is measured in bits/month - and you can count 'em on one hand! :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.  There are some things you can do that might the data load go faster, such as use sql loader if you are doing individual inserts, and increasing your commit interval.  However, I would have to see the code to really help very much.

Comment: Yup, I did add commits. Also constraints are created after the data is imported. But unfortunately no way to work around the network hop :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the remote server on which the database is hosted and you have access to execute **sqlplus** on the said server, sure you can.

1. Login or SSH (depending upon OS - Windows or *nix) to the
   server
2. Create your SQL script (myscript.sql) over there.
3. Login to SQL*Plus and execute using the command *@ myscript.sql*

Answer (score 0):

There is rarely a need to run these kinds of scripts on the server.  A few simple changes to batch commands can significantly improve performance.  All of the changes below combine multiple statements, reducing the number of network round-trips.  Some of them also decrease parsing time, which will significantly improve performance even if the scripts run on the server.

**Combine INSERTs into a single statement**

Replace individual inserts:

```
insert into some_table values(1);
insert into some_table values(2);
...
```

with combind inserts like this:

```
insert into some_table
select 1 from dual union all
select 2 from dual union all
...
```

**Use PL/SQL blocks**

Replace individual DDL:

```
create sequence sequence1;
create sequence sequence2;
```

with a PL/SQL block:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'create sequence sequence1';
    execute immediate 'create sequence sequence2';
end;
/
```

**Use inline constraints**

Combine DDL as much as possible.  For example, use this statement:

```
create table some_table(a number not null);
```

Instead of this:

```
create table some_table(a number);
alter table some_table modify a not null;
```